# How to remove duplicate items from a list using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How to remove duplicate items from a list using list comprehension? I have following code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2, 8, 5, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 5, 8]
b = []
b = [item for item in a if item not in b]
```

but it doesn't work, just produces identical list. Why its producing an identical list?

Comment: Because `b` is empty at the moment you execute `if item not in b`. The list comprehension is done in memory and the result is assigned to `b` at the end.

Comment: That means list comprehension doesn't work like loop?

Comment: If you don't want to use a set because you want to preserve the order, look at the `unique_everseen` iterator in the [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes). Use like this: `b = list(unique_everseen(a))`

Comment: It's kind of a loop, but it generates the result in one go... it's not that surprising either. Whenever you have the expression `x = y`, then `y` is evaluated first and then the result is assigned to `x`. But during evaluation of `y`, `x` is not modified. Would you have had the same doubts if you had `b = list(item for item in a if item not in b)` instead?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's producing an identical list as `b` contains no elements at run-time.
What you'd want it this:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2, 8, 5, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 5, 8]
>>> b = []
>>> [b.append(item) for item in a if item not in b]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 6, 8, 7]
```

Comment: Beware of using [list comprehensions for side effects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5753597/566644). Use a regular for loop instead.

Comment: This is also a `O(n²)` answer, where, for hashable inputs, `O(n)` is possible ([with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65227764/364696) or [without](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10549362/364696) preserving order), and for nonhashable, but sortable inputs, `O(n log n)` is possible (though it replaces original ordering with sorted ordering unless you go to some effort to decorate and undecorate the inputs with their index and incorporate it in the sorting and deduplication so a second sort can restore the original ordering).

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind using a different technique than list comprehension you can use a set for that:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2, 8, 5, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 5, 8]
>>> b = list(set(a))
>>> print b
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I have looked at set function, just want to know what's wrong with above code and if it could be corrected?

Comment: set will not keep the initial order... so just take notice of that

Comment: @AdiRoiban: That [can be fixed with minimal code changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65227764/364696). It's slower than using `set`, but not *much* slower if you're on 3.6+ (if you're on 3.5 and earlier using `OrderedDict`, it's a bigger hit; >3x runtime, while 3.6+ with plain `dict` is only about a 66% increase in runtime).

Answer (score 5):

Use `keys` on a `dict` constructed with values in `a` as its keys.

```
b = dict([(i, 1) for i in a]).keys()
```

Or use a set:

```
b = [i for i in set(a)]
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason that the list is unchanged is that `b` starts out empty. This means that `if item not in b` is always `True`. Only after the list has been generated is this new non-empty list assigned to the variable `b`.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, that means list comprehension adds items at one go instead of checking and adding each item one at a time like in loop.

Comment: @Alinwndrld: I don't think that's a valid conclusion. It only means that the list comprehension is evaluated before the assignment. The list may well be built up in a loop internally.

Answer (score 4):

Use [groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2, 8, 5, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 5, 8]
>>> [k for k, _ in groupby(sorted(a, key=lambda x: a.index(x)))]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 6, 8, 7]
```

Leave out the key argument if you don't care about which order the value first appeared in the original list, e.g.

```
>>> [k for k, _ in groupby(sorted(a))]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You can do some cool things with `groupby`. To identify items that appear multiple times:

```
>>> [k for k, v in groupby(sorted(a)) if len(list(v)) > 1]
[2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Or to build up a frequency dictionary:

```
>>> {k: len(list(v)) for k, v in groupby(sorted(a))}
{1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 4, 5: 4, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 1}
```

There are some very useful functions in the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module: `chain`, `tee` and `product` to name a few!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [10,20,30,20,10,50,60,40,80,50,40,0,100,30,60]
>>> [a.pop(a.index(i, a.index(i)+1)) for i in a if a.count(i) > 1]
>>> print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> repeated_items = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,1,1,1]
>>> [
...     next(group)
...     for _, group in groupby(
...         repeated_items,
...         key=repeated_items.index
...     )
... ]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Comment: Clever solution, I like it. Downside is the `index` call, which makes it `O(n²)`, and the assumption that the input is already grouped (it won't work on `[2,1,2]`). You could solve both problems, *and* still preserve input order, with a modified Schwartzian Transform (requires `from itertools import count, groupby`): `[v for v, _ in sorted([next(grp) for _, grp in groupby(sorted(zip(repeated_items, count())), key=lambda x: x[0])], key=lambda x: x[1])]`. Might not be worth the trouble, but I love a good bit of `itertools` powered insanity.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.6+, there is an improvement to be had over [Niek de Klein's mostly excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10549362/364696) (it's primary flaw being that it loses input ordering). Since `dict`s are now insertion-ordered, you can just do:

```
b = list(dict.fromkeys(a))
```

On earlier Python, you'd do:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

b = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(a))
```

It's not nearly as fast though (even when `OrderedDict` was moved to the C layer, it kept a lot of overhead to support reordering operations that `dict`, which doesn't support them, avoids).