# Remove duplicates from a list

Tags: python

I wrote the following code to remove duplicates from a list:

```
def remove_duplicates(listy):
    new_listy = []
    for i in range(len(listy)):
        a = listy.pop(i)
        while a in listy:
            listy = listy.remove(a)

        else: new_listy.append(a)
    return new_listy
```

The following error is given when running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#93>", line 1, in <module>
    remove_duplicates([1,1,2,2])
  File "C:\Python27\MIT_4.py", line 4, in remove_duplicates
    a = listy.pop(i)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop.
```

What is causing this error?  How can it be fixed to solve this correctly?

Comment: Pay attention, that when an item removed from listy, len(listy) is changed; usually we loop in reverse: from len(listy) - 1 downto 0

Comment: Do you care about the order of the elements? If not, you can make a `set` out of the original list, then make a list out of that.

Answer (score 2):

To remove duplicates, you can use the `set` function if ordering is not important. But if your intention is to learn python, then it is important to know what is wrong with your code.

This is very unpythonic: `for i in range(len(listy)):`

Use instead, `for item in listy:`

Using `a = listy.pop(i)` this way will cause problems because within the loop list elements are being removed. Elements which were there at the start of the loop will no longer be available when `pop()` executes..

Remove function does not return a list! So this is wrong: `listy = listy.remove(a)`

There is no need to remove from listy since you are making a new list anyway. If you wish to update listy, assign the function's return value to listy.

One way to remove duplicates and return a new list preserving the original order:

```
def remove_duplicates(listy):
    new_listy = []
    for item in listy:
        if item not in new_listy:
            new_listy.append(item)
    return new_listy
```

Comment: I did find one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549345/how-to-remove-duplicate-items-from-a-list-using-list-comprehension

Answer (score 0):

to remove duplicates you can use set function

```
lst = [1,1,1,2,3,4]
print list(set(lst))
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Note that the retained order here is a "fluke"; if order is important, this will not work in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have rearranged your function a bit and it will give you the desired result

```
list1 = [1,1,2,2,3]
def remove_duplicates(listy):
    new_listy = []
    for i in listy:
        if i not in new_listy:
            new_listy.append(i)
    return new_listy
print remove_duplicates(list1)

Output: [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

lista.remove does not create a new list, so you cannot assign the result like this:

```
listy = listy.remove(a)
```

Then listy is None and you get errors trying to call pop() on None instead of the list.

Also there are other errors in your code. I suggest reading the documentation for these commands so you understand them better.