# Extract unique list from nested list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to extract unique data from nested list, see below. I implemented two way of this. First one works good, but second one failed. Is `new_data` is empty during calculation? And how do I fix it?

```
 data = [                                                                                                                                      
     ['a', 'b'],                                                                                                                               
     ['a', 'c'],                                                                                                                               
     ['a', 'b'],                                                                                                                               
     ['b', 'a']                                                                                                                                
 ]                                                                                                                                             

 # working                                                                                                                                          
 new_data = []                                                                                                                                 
 for d in data:                                                                                                                                
     if d not in new_data:                                                                                                                     
         new_data.append(d)                                                                                                                    
 print(new_data)                                                                                                                               
 # [['a', 'b'], ['a','c'], ['b','a']]                                                                                                          

 # Failed to extract unique list                                                                                                                                 
 new_data = []                                                                                                                                 
 new_data = [d for d in data if d not in new_data]                                                                                             
 print(new_data)                                                                                                                               
 # [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a']]
```

Comment: Yes, `new_data` is empty during the execution of the list comprehension, the results of which are assigned to `new_data` after execution.

Comment: Just use your original version... that's how you fix it.

Comment: There is nothing in `new_data` when you test: `if d not in new_data`. List comprehensions run to completion before continuing to the assignment operator to save the result back to `new_data`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549345/how-to-remove-duplicate-items-from-a-list-using-list-comprehension)  Q&A explains why the list comprehension doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

Just try:

```
new_data = [list(y) for y in set([tuple(x) for x in data])]
```

You cannot use `set()` on a list of lists because lists are not hashable. You convert the list of lists into a list of tuples. Apply `set()` to remove the duplicates. Then convert the de duplicated list of tuples back into a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `enumerate` to test that there are no copies before the current value such that only the first instance of a copy is taken:

```
new_data = [item for index, item in enumerate(data) if item not in data[:index]]
```