# unique list from list of list in python

Tags: python

I want the unique list from the following list of list.

```
A = [[-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]
output = [[-1,0,1], [-1,-1,2]]
```

I don't want to use any package.
could you help me with that?

Comment: this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46694524/1836069

Comment: `list(set(map(tuple, A)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use set to get a unique list from number of lists

```
unique_data = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in A)]
```

This will generate your expected output. :)

Comment: @Meskaj  Can you please accept the answer so if anyone who in search of same question then he/she will get to know that solutions is worked.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct but it doesn't maintain the original list order.

In case the order is important to you :

```
A = [['a', 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2], ['a', 0, 1]]
res = [list(i) for i in dict.fromkeys(map(tuple, A))]
print(res)
```

output :

```
[['a', 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2]]
```

**Note** : I've put `'a'` inside the sub lists in order to show you that in several runs you will get different result by using sets in other solution. Dictionaries maintain the insertion order now.