# Output using list comprehension different from output using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have only recently started learning Python, and have no experience coding. I'm trying to write code that, given a list of numbers, returns another (ordered) list of numbers without any of the duplicates present in the first list.

The following code seems to work:

```
nums = [2, 2, 1, 3]
r = []
for i in nums:
    if i not in r:
        r.append(i)
print(sorted(r))
```

Output is:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I then tried the same using list comprehension, but apparently got something wrong. This is what I tried:

```
nums = [2, 2, 1, 3]
r = []
r = sorted([i for i in nums if i not in r])
print(r)
```

And this is the output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `r` doesn't get updated in list comprehension - it stays at `[]` until sorted is done and result assigned to `r`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove duplicate items from a list using list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549345/how-to-remove-duplicate-items-from-a-list-using-list-comprehension)

Comment: I'm really not sure why this question was voted down and closed as "not suitable for this site". It's a perfectly valid question, though it's already been asked.

Comment: @stovfl could you chime in on why you voted to close the question? Keep in mind this is OP's first post.

Comment: @MrNobody33 could you chime in on why you voted to close the question? Keep in mind this is OP's first post.

Comment: @wjandrea, it does answer it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `r` doesn't update in your list comprehension (`[i for i in nums if i not in r]`), so it will be empty every time that you check your condition.

Also, for sorting unique list with numbers, use set like:
`sorted(set(nums))`